# How to get the column index number of a specific field name in a staged file on Snowflake?

Tags: sql, merge, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, staging

I need to get the column number of a staged file on Snowflake.

The main idea behind it, is that I need to automate getting this field in other queries rather than using `t.$3` whereas 3 is the position of the field, that might be changed because we are having an expandable surveys (more or less questions depending on the situation).

So what I need is something like that:

```
SELECT COL_NUMBER FROM @my_stage/myfile.csv  WHERE value = 'my_column_name` 
-- Without any file format to read the header
```

And then this `COL_NUMBER` could be user as `t.$"+COL_NUMBER+"` inside merge queries.

Comment: probably the easiest way to do this is in your client (Python, Go, etc.). You select all columns, find the position of your column and generate the sql statement.

Comment: @Zephro I am doing a JavaScript procedure, how can I achieve this with JS?

Comment: a Snowflake stored procedure?

Comment: @Zephro yes in a snowflake stored procedure.